# Scaling up/down entire page with Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-5

I've created a pretty simple webpage using Bootstrap 5 and I'm broadly happy with how it looks. However, all the body elements are simply too large.

[Elements too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdtON.png)

Notice that the elements at the bottom are being cut off. I'd like the entire page to be viewable on a typical 1080p computer screen, here's an example (manually zooming out on the browser).

[More what I'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hm38.png)

Is there an ideal way of sizing everything down?

I've looked over the Bootstrap docs and didn't find and didn't find an answer, but I have about a week's experience with it so I'm sure I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reducing the body default font-size and form elements line heights and padding.

Since, bootstrap v5 comes with bigger font-size defaulting at 16px. But under special cases (like your scenario) we need to touch down the below properties.

```
font-size
padding
line-height.
```

Reduce the above properties and try to fit your site properly for width 1080px.

You can even take the help of media-queries. For example,

**focusing only on width-1080px**

```
@media (width: 1080px) {
    body {background-color: red !important}
}
```

**focusing on width 1080px and less**

```
@media (max-width: 1080px) {
    body {background-color: red !important}
}
```

**focusing on width 1080px and more**

```
@media (min-width: 1080px) {
    body {background-color: red !important}
}
```

Comment: Adjusting the font size seemed to do the trick. Bootstrap is pretty slick so I thought maybe there was a better built-in way of doing it. The page looks much more reasonable now.

Comment: I think in bootstrap-5 units are in rem. So, I think change in the font size is enough. Prior versions had lot of issues as they rely on the pixels unit rather than rem unit.